# Symfony : issue with PropertyAccessor

Tags: symfony, properties, accessor

I have an issue with the propertyAccessor : There are the two following entities :

```
class Foo
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bar", inversedBy="foo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $bar;

    public function getBar(): ?Bar
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    public function setBar(?Bar $bar): self
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
        return $this;
    }
}


class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Foo", mappedBy="bar", orphanRemoval=true, cascade="all")
     */
    private $foo

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Foo[]
     */
    public function getFoo(): Collection
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }

    public function addFoo(Foo $foo): self
    {
        if (!$this->foo->contains($foo)) {
            $this->foo[] = $foo;
            $foo->setBar($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFoo(Foo $foo): self
    {
        if ($this->foo->contains($foo)) {
            $this->foo->removeElement($foo);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($foo->getBar() === $this) {
                $foo->setBar(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

I have plenty of Collections such as Foo, so I use the property accessor to access them programmatically. But when I do a :

```
            $bar = new Bar();
            $foo = new Foo();
            $propertyAccessor->getValue($bar, 'foo')->add($foo);
```

the `$foo->bar` stay at null.

Is it normal?

Will then orphean removal still work?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValue` method supports adding to a collection. You should call this method directly for `$bar`.

```
$propertyAccessor->setValue($bar, 'foo', [$foo]);
```

For more information, see [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html#writing-to-array-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected.

`$propertyAccessor->getValue($bar, 'foo')` will return an instance of `ArrayCollection`. And calling `add($foo)` on the collection, won't magically set `$foo->bar`. I guess you mixed it up with `addFoo()` on `Bar`.

To your second question: Calling `$bar->removeFoo($anyFoo)` will trigger a removal of the `$anyFoo` representation in the database.